# Convert avro schema to pyarrow schema

Tags: python, avro, parquet, pyarrow

How can I transform an avro schema to a pyarrow schema?

I am reading an avsc file with a schema and I want to pass it to `beam.writeToParquet(filename,schema)`

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to kafka's avro schema to pyarrow schema?
I also had to solve a similar problem, and wanted to solve it by using `schema registry`, but couldn't. So I solved it like below.

If you change avro's schema to pyarrow's schema, I tihnk that the most Simple mathod is 'pyarrow - from_pandas'.

So, I recommend to use `pa.Schema.from_pandas`

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pandas as pd

def return_pyarrow_schema(record: str(dict)):
    return pa.Schema.from_pandas(
                pd.DataFrame(
                    eval(record),
                    index=[0],
                )
            )
```

If you get this error `​KeyError: ‘__index_level_0__’`
Modify code like below.

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pandas as pd

def return_pyarrow_schema(record: str(dict)):
    return pa.Schema.from_pandas(
                pd.DataFrame(
                    eval(record),
                    index=[0],
                ),
           preserve_index=False,
            )
```

I think you can solve it based on this.
And I think the link below will be helpful for you.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74188574

Comment: No need to worry over your language skill, it is good enough and better than many. Have fun and good luck.