# How to get the schema from parquet in Python apache-beam

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, parquet, pyarrow

I currently have an apache-beam pipeline in Python in which I'm reading parquet, converting it to a dataframe to do some pandas cleaning, and then converting back to parquet where I'd like to then write the file. It looks like this:

```py
  with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:

    dataframes = p \
      | 'Read' >> beam.io.ReadFromParquetBatched(known_args.input) \
      | 'Convert to pandas' >> beam.Map(lambda table: table.to_pandas()) \
      | 'Process df' >> beam.ParDo(ProcessDataFrame()) \
      | 'Convert to parquet' >> beam.Map(lambda table: table.to_parquet()) \
      | 'Write to parquet' >> beam.io.WriteToParquet(known_args.output)
```

However this returns an error as expected because I'm missing the schema as an argument to `WriteToParquet`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kgallatin/dataflow/example.py", line 75, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/kgallatin/dataflow/example.py", line 70, in main
    | 'Write to parquet' >> beam.io.WriteToParquet(known_args.output)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'schema'
```

I have 100-1000s of columns that potentially will change over the lifetime of this pipeline, so I'd like to avoid manually writing them all in the pyarrow format as described [here](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.11.0/apache_beam.io.parquetio.html#apache_beam.io.parquetio.WriteToParquet). When I print the parquet from the previous step I can see a pandas schema and some binary pyarrow stuff - is there a way to extract the schema from the parquet at this step for use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code`table.to_parquet()` returns serialized bytes of all of the records in Parquet format.

Currently, `WriteToParquet()` need a manually given fixed schema. So, you have to implement your own pipeline(`PTransform`) if you want to generate a schema automatically.

If you don't need a parallelism(such as sharding), you can do like the following using the low level API.

```
...
import pyarrow as pa
from apache_beam.io.filesystems import FileSystems
from apache_beam.io.filesystem import CompressionTypes
...
def write_dataframe_to_parquet(frame):
    table = pa.Table.from_pandas(frame)
    with FileSystems.create(known_args.output,
            mime_type='application/x-parquet',
            compression_type=CompressionTypes.UNCOMPRESSED,
        ) as f:
        pa.parquet.write_table(table, f)    
...
dataframes = p \
      ...
      | 'Process df' >> beam.ParDo(ProcessDataFrame()) \
      | 'Write to parquet' >> beam.Map(write_dataframe_to_parquet)
```

Comment: Excellent, I can confirm this works for my local file system - happen to know if `apache_beam.io.filesystems.FileSystems` works with GCS?

Comment: Yes it works with GCS. It is the backend of the various readers and writers of io module.

Comment: And on parallelism, you just mean on the write process correct? Since beam/dataflow uses multiprocessing this would still be easy to distributed across a number of parquet files on a number of dataflow workers.

Comment: Yes you are right. APIs like ```WriteToParquet``` and ```FileBasedSink``` supports sharding.